# Optimization of geodata search

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, geolocation

I'm developing an application in which I need to search if there are some items in a geographical area. Those items are saved with their latitude and longitude in a database, in a table with also other information. What I need to do is basically search in a round area centered in some coordinates for all the items in the database. Right now I'm just making a query getting all the data and then making some calculations for each item to see if it is within the area (basically Pythagorean theorem as I don't need too much precision).

Can someone who has already done something like this give some advice on how to optimize it? Maybe also with some kind of cacheing system that returns result gathered by previous searches in the general area, precision of the area is not crucial and shifting the circle by few km would not be a problem.

I'm using MySQL for the database and PHP is what should produce my result.
Thank you in advance

**EDIT**
I've not posted the code because I'm not asking for specific code modification but more of an intuitive way to solve the problem, some kind of algorithm which I can later codify myself.

Anyway this is the database structure

```
Table Interv

ID Int
Addr Text
Info Text
Area Int
Type Text
Lat Double
Lng Double
Time Datetime

Table Area

ID Int
Name Text
```

And this is the PHP page

```
require("Utils.php");
    require("Config.php");
    
    if(!array_key_exists("Lat",$_GET) || !array_key_exists("Lng",$_GET)){
        $re = array("error"=>"1");
        echo json_encode($re);
        exit();
    } 
    $lat = $_GET["Lat"];
    $lng = $_GET["Lng"];
    
    $mysqli = get_mysqli();
    $query = "SELECT `Interv`.`Addr`,`Interv`.`Info`,`Interv`.`Lat`,`Interv`.`Lng`,`Interv`.`Type`, `Area`.`Name` FROM `Interv` JOIN `Area` ON `Interv`.`Area`=`Area`.`ID` WHERE  `Time` > '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",(time() - Max_Time))."';";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    if($result->num_rows >0){
        $responce = array("Error" => 0 , "Data" => array());
        $i = 0;
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            if(sqrt(pow($lat-$row["Lat"],2)+pow($lng-$row["Lng"],2)) < Max_Distance){
                $responce["Data"][$i] = array("Addr" => $row["Addr"], "Info" => $row["Info"], "Type" => $row["Type"], "Area" => $row["Name"]);
                $i++;
            }
        
        }
        echo json_encode($responce);
        $result->close();
    }
    $mysqli->close();
```

I thought of using Google's API to compute the distance, but I think that would completely kill the server bandwidth so I'm not sure how to approach this problem.

Thanks again

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We can't possibly help to optimise your code without you **posting** it! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Edited adding the relevant code

Answer (score 0):

This is an unoptimized as well as mathematically incorrect way of doing geographical spherical distances.

1. You are brute forcing by selecting all the data, and the filtering it based on pythagorean calculations.
2. Pythagorean calculations for linear distances are inaccurate for geosphere data as Earth has curvature, and is not a plain. The better approximation is the [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) approach. Its implementation is easily available in all programming languages. But you do not even have to use this in your case, as your case can be solved at the database level itself, as most modern databases support geospatical data.

For mysql 5.6+, geospatial data types and querying is inbuilt. So you can just store all your data along with the coordinates, and do a single query to find all points which lie within specific circular range. A good explaination [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-mysql-spatial-functions-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/), and official doc [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-datatypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

For up to, say, 10K points, this will probably do good enough:

Add a "bounding box" to the `WHERE` clause and have `INDEX(latitude), INDEX(longitude)`.

You need to divide by the `COS(lat)` to compensate for longitude lines being closer together than latitude lines.

Pythagorean distance *may be* good enough for 'small' distances that are not near the poles nor crossing the dateline.  Again, `COS` is needed.

I added a tag; see other discussions thusly tagged.